# laravel - 3 steps relation by many to many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

I have 3 tabels: users, teachers And posts.

> **users**:
>       id - integer
>       name - string
>
> **teachers**:
>       id - integer
>       teacher_id - integer
>       user_id - integer
>       name - string
>
> **posts**:
>       id - integer
>       user_id - integer
>       title - string

**User** Model:

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function teachers()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Teacher');
  }
}
```

**Teacher** Model:

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id','teacher_id');
  }
}
```

**?** ***Question*** is How can I use sth like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$teacher_posts = $user->teachers()->posts
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of new to laravel but here is my take.

What I have realized is that typically your many to many relationships will require a pivot table.

**users**:(id, name)

**teachers**:(id, teacher_id, name)

**teacher_users**:(id, user_id, teacher_id)

**posts**:(id, user_id, title)

And your Eloquent models will look like this.

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function teachers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher');
  }

  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
  }
}


class Teacher extends Model
{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
  }
}

$user = User::find(1);
$user_posts = $user->posts();
```

[Check out the documentation here for more details](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)